# Using a different domain for each language in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-10, laravel-localization

I am building a website in Laravel and need to use a different domain for each language.
Currently I'm using `mcamara/laravel-localization` for the localization.
For example:

- EN => my-english-website.com
- NL => my-dutch-website.com

It seems like using different domains is not something that is supported by default.
Has someone run into this issue and knows how to solve this?

Comment: What about [subdomain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing)?
Also, you need to share more details about the actual problem with your current implementation

Comment: Interesting. This might be an option if it also works with entirely different domains.
There is not much to explain about the current implementation since the package I'm using does not seem to support multiple domains. I have never done this with Laravel and I am asking the community what a best practice solution is in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subdomains are supported by default.

```php
Route::domain('{locale}.website.com')->middleware('set-locale')->group(function () {
    // your routes here
})->where('locale', '(my-english|my-dutch|my-spanish)');
```

You use `where` to match the {locale} parameter to a regex pattern and then use a middleware to actually set the locale.

Maybe you'd have something like this in the middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $locales = ['my-english' => 'en', 'my-spanish' => 'es', ...];

    app()->setLocale($locales[$this->route->parameter('locale')]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

I'm not sure if this was the correct syntax, but you get the idea.

Comment: It seems like this is the way to go.
Thanks @hassan and @IGP!